# What is the name of this division algorithm?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, floating-point, computer-science

I have an algorithm performing division of the mantissas for Floating Point Division, but I'm not sure **what is the proper name for the algorithm *posted below*** (e.g. restoring, non-restoring, SRT).

For dealing with the fact that my inputs are in floating point format, I subtracted the operand exponents to find the new exponent, XOR'd the sign bits to get the new sign bit, and performed round to nearest for the rounding scheme.

BUT, I used this algorithm from wikipedia for dividing the mantissas: 
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm):

Here is my code:

```
{Code for handling exponent, sign bit, and grabbing mantissa, 
invalid input detection and zero input detection}
{op1 is the numerator, op2 is the divisor)
{assuming 32-bit floating point)

long long mant1, mant2;

mant1 = (1 << 23) & (op1 & 0x7FFFFF); // Make mantissas with hidden bit masked in
mant2 = (1 << 23) & (op2 & 0x7FFFFF);


long long Q = 0, N, D; // Declare quotient, numerator, and divisor
N = mant1 << 26;
D = mant2 << 26;

for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
  Q = Q << 1; // Multiply quotient by 2

  if (N-D < 1) {
    N = N-D;   // Set new numerator equal to difference
    Q = Q | 1; // Set LSB of quotient to 1
  }

  D = D >> 1; // Shift divider right by 1;
}
```

The algorithm is similar to one called  ***Integer division (unsigned) with remainder*** according to wikipedia, but in all other literature of floating point division algorithms, I haven't been able to find a reference to such an algorithm, the closest that seems to match this description is ***true division***.  For that reason, I wanted to check with the community on what the proper name for this division algorithm is called.

Extra notes: I am aware that there is a floating point instruction in C and C++, I am writing and testing this algorithm since I am implementing it for a hardware design.  However, I want to use this algorithm since it appears to have a low area overhead, although high latency (which is okay for my embedded platform).

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think this code is for floating point? It doesn't seem to reference the exponents anywhere. And it doesn't just look similar to that algorithm in Wikipedia, it looks like a verbatim copy of it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. If you have a question about a particular piece of code, post THAT code, not the code from Wikipedia that it resembles.

Comment: Anyway, this isn't a programming question. An algorithm by any name would smell as sweet.

Comment: I doubt many programmers even know this algorithm has a name, or even care. 99% of us never have to code a division algorithm. If you're programming in a HLL, you just use its division operator; if you're programming assembler you use the division instruction. This is just a trivia question, not a practical programming problem.

Comment: I know this as a "non-performing" bitwise division. Instead of subtracting the divisor and restoring if the remainder is negative, compare first and only subtract if the remainder is known to be positive.

Comment: Anyway, on a more pragmatic level... What is your question?? Superficially your question seems to be: what is the name of an algorithm that I'm not going to show to you, and that is very similar to "Integer division (unsigned) with remainder".

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: The question has been updated.